# Android - Throwing Network Traffic Data To Mobile Network While WLAN is Turned On

Tags: android, networking

Our app allows user to remote control a Wi-Fi device. This means that no matter what the user should turn on his/her WLAN in settings. However, while connected to the Wi-Fi device, the user will not be able to use his mobile network to access the internet, because Wi-Fi has higher priority than mobile network.

We tried to forcibly set the DNS value in WiFi Settings to 0 so that the system would think that no network access is available in Wi-Fi, then it will focus all the network traffic to mobile network. However, it doesn't work.

Do you have any other solution to this? Thanks!